# C# WebService Client Raw INPUT/OUTPUT

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, debugging

Quick question:

Is there a way to print **raw input/output XML** on a C#/.NET WebService Client?

In C#, I have this call:

```
BWSC.MyClient client = new BWSC.MyClient();
client.MyCall("p1", "p2);
```

I want to see what's the exact output XML that client is generating, and the exact input XML server is responding.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why dont you use [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp) to see the request/response to the server? That way you wouldn't have to change your code!

Answer (score 3):

You would have to write a simple SoapExtension that outputs the raw SOAP messages. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextension%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

soapUI is good for this, too.

http://www.soapui.org/